# What is the last version of Ubuntu 32-bit that downloadable for desktop with Intel processor

Tags: intel, cpu, 32-bit

Hope you don't mind my question. I would like to know what is the last version of Ubuntu for desktop with Intel processor. I check [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/#download), the last is Ubuntu 18.10 AMD64. Appreciated if someone can provide with a downloadable link.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you want.  Lubuntu & Xubuntu stopped producing i386 (or really i686) releases in December 2018 so 18.10 was the last released in 32bit (requiring PAE processor or 686 class), dailies for 19.04 were produced till early & late dec-2018.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and many flavors beyond those i've already mentioned) was the last ISO with desktop pre-installed, but i386 (i686 with PAE) are still produced but you need to add the desktop yourself past 18.04.2 LTS.  If you need non-PAE 32bit you have to go older for support.

Comment: You got my question. I intend to install Ubuntu in my laptop with intel 32-bit processor. But when I look in the website, there is no for Intel 32-bit. When I clicked the download, that is came to *ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso*. I didn't know if Ubuntu has ceased to provide Ubuntu for Intel processor.

Comment: But there is probably version from years back to installable on my laptop. Do you know what is the last version available to Intel 32-bit?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 was only produced for x86_64 (called amd64 as AMD was first with 64bit).  Ubuntu itself only i386 via alternative download (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)  but as stated, Lubuntu 18.10 provided a x86 (32bit PAE i686) image as did Xubuntu 18.10. x86 or 32bit is still produced, but NOT with desktop pre-installed.

Comment: Here is the link for Ubuntu 18.10 x86  (network installer) - http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/   There are many choices; the latest could mean 19.04 (daily image so fresh daily), but could mean latest LTS (thus 18.04 LTS) or latest release (normal support 18.10) - ie. your question was vague.

Comment: Thank your for the link. I am just looking for installer for Intel 32-bit version that I want to install to my laptop.

Comment: Again you have choices.  LTS are long-term-support releases, and 18.04 LTS has five years of support (3 if flavor is chosen) thus will outlive the later 18.10 release. Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, so both those I mentioned are 2018 releases (long-term-support release was in April, normal release was in October).  Your use, laptop (cpu class, memory etc) would direct my choice (including desktop which is also subjective likes/dislikes)  - not the age of Ubuntu release.  If you like release-upgrading often go 18.10, if not then go older 18.04 LTS.  Download & try it on your machine.

Comment: I was Ubuntu user back to 8 years ago (2000 to 2011). But then I stopped for some reasons. Now I would like to back to ubuntu. So I am not actually very new to ubuntu. But I got confuse how to find the 32-bit version for Intel. As you mentioned, Ubuntu now only supports AMD. No wonder.

Comment: Ubuntu DOES support intel.  Even microsoft refer to 64bit as AMD64 because that's it's correct name. Intel's IA64 was not x86 compatible so AMD64 is the 64bit version of the old x86 (x86_64 == AMD64).   *Intel in due course dropped IA64 & use AMD64 also!*

Comment: Several flavors of Ubuntu have found the 32-bit user experience to be wanting, and some projects lack enough 32-bit developers to maintain their codebase. Those flavors have (understandably) dropped 32-bit Desktop installers and are phasing out 32-bit support as older releases expire. However, all releases of Ubuntu still build 32-bit packages from source, and alternatives like the Minimal and Network installers are still available..

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 32Bit can be found here: https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released/ .There is no Ubuntu 18.04 32bit.